# Strange behavior reading Dictionary from a plist file

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, nsmutabledictionary

When I read a plist for a dictionary which is **not empty** and has at-least one key value pair into an NSMutableDictionary property of my model class, Everything works fine.
I can add,delete modify the mutable dictionary.

But when the dictionary **is empty**

and you can see the plist with a tag like this :

`<dict/>`

Then, even though my property has an NSMutableDictionary pointer, Object which is created becomes immutable.

and when I try to set an object in it for a particular property,
It gives me this error saying:

`'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutable = [yourApparentlyMutableDictionary mutableCopy];
```

Comment: myApparentlyMutableDictionary is a class property which I need to modify.
So shall I load it into a temporary mutableCopy change the copy and assign it back ?
If yes, shall I keep the mutableCopy auto-released or release when I am done ?

Comment: Cool! Objective C is a bit different to some of the more common languages, but learning it is a lot of fun!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure all objects retrieved from a plist are the immutable variants. I do think I saw an option to deserialize them as mutable however.

Edit:

this article explains how to unarchive  a plist as mutable:

http://cocoadev.com/wiki/PropertyList